# JQuery Fancybox - changing url and access diretely to it

Tags: jquery

Basically, I need that fancybox change url in the address bar, I have urls that look like this :

```
<li><a href="http://www.test.com/test/page/index" data-fancybox-href="http://www.test.com/test/page/index" id="page/index" class="list-group-item">Pages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.test.com/test/gallery/index" data-fancybox-href="http://www.test.com/test/gallery/index" id="gallery/index" class="list-group-item">Gallery</a></li>
```

Here's my script:

```
var current_hash = '';
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list-group-item').fancybox({
        prevEffect: 'fade',
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        closeBtn: true,
        arrows: true,
        type: 'iframe',
        nextClick: true,
        padding: 15,
        helpers: {
            thumbs: {
                width: 80,
                height: 80
            }
        },

        beforeShow: function() {
            var id = this.element.attr("id")
            current_hash = id;
            if (id) {
                window.location.hash = current_hash;
            }
        },
        beforeClose : function() {
            current_hash = false;
        },
        afterClose : function() {

            if ("pushState" in history) {
                history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
            } else {
                window.location.hash = "";
            }
        }

    });
    if (thisHash) {

        $(thisHash).trigger('click');

    }
});
```

The first issue here is the selector `"id"`, is it okay if an id have this syntax `id="page/index"`, because when I try to access to the url directly it doesn't work, so I tried `id="page_index"` and it worked but it doesn't look good at the url bar, so any way I can have the url I want? Second, any way I can have another selector like `"id"` ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in html5 you are able to give your elements [data-attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

e.g.

```
<li><a href="http://www.test.com/test/page/index" data-fancybox-href="http://www.test.com/test/page/index" data-change-link="page/index" id="myIdentifier" class="list-group-item">Pages</a></li>
```

in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/data/) you have access on your data attributes in the following way:

```
$('#selector').data('change-link');
```

or

```
$('#selector').attr('data-change-link');
```